# symfony2 render controller with get parameters

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How to render a controller with get parameters in twig?

```
{{ render(controller('AutoBundle:MyController:main', { 'id': id, 'active': true } )) }}
```

to call controller like this: https://example.com/users/323?active=true

Comment: This code snippet should work, what do you intend to do exactly ?

Comment: you need to get this parameters (id and active) from the current request?

Comment: `$request->query->get('active')` -> "NULL"... weird :S

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In accordion with the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#controller) the query argument is the third parameters.

> {{ controller(controller, attributes, query) }}

So try this:

```
{{ render(controller('AutoBundle:MyController:main', {}, { 'id': id, 'active': true } )) }}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it doesn't send the parameters as a GET request, but seems to call the method directly.

Twig template part:

```
<div id="question-choose-semester">
    {{ render(controller('UnswCamsBundle:Semester:choiceAjax', { 'redirect':  path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params'))} )) }}
</div>
```

Create an optional parameter. If using annotations to define the route, you don't have to add it to the annotation specification.

```
  public function choiceAjaxAction($redirect = "", Request $request) {
```

Then check the GET parameter:

```
if (empty($redirect)) {
  $redirect_uri = $request->query->get('Redirect');
} else {
```